# AsyncWait in Lely CANopen is not behaving asynchronously?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, fibers, canopen

I'm trying to perform some tasks using fibers in the Lely CANopen stack. However, I either don't understand the model, or something is broken. What I would like to do is run multiple tasks at different rates.

An example based on the tutorial [here](https://opensource.lely.com/canopen/docs/cpp-tutorial/):

```c++
class MyDriver : public canopen::FiberDriver {
 public:
  using FiberDriver::FiberDriver;

 private:
  // Configure device
  void OnConfig(std::function<void(std::error_code ec)> res) noexcept override {
    try {
      // Do some SDO configuration

      // Schedule tasks
      Defer(&MyDriver::TaskA, this);
      Defer(&MyDriver::TaskB, this);

      // Return no error
      res({});
    } catch (canopen::SdoError& e) {
      res(e.code());
    }
  }

  void TaskA() noexcept {
    while (true) {
      // Do some processing
      std::cout << "Hello from task A" << std::endl;

      // Wait
      Wait(AsyncWait(duration(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000))));
    }
  }

  void TaskB() noexcept {
    while (true) {
      // Do some processing
      std::cout << "Hello from task B" << std::endl;

      // Wait
      Wait(AsyncWait(duration(std::chrono::milliseconds(500))));
    }
  }

};

int main() {
  // A lot of set up omitted for clarity
  // Create context, event loop, CAN channel, etc.

  // Create master
  canopen::AsyncMaster master(timer, chan, "../config/master.dcf", "", 1);

  // Start NMT service by pretending to get a reset command
  master.Reset();

  // Create a driver for CAN device
  MyDriver driver(exec, master, 2);

  // Run the event loop
  loop.run();

  return 0;
}
```

I would expect this to print something like:

```
Hello from task A
Hello from task B
Hello from task B
Hello from task A
Hello from task B
Hello from task B
...
```

However, I get output like this:

```
Hello from task A
Hello from task A
Hello from task A
Hello from task A
...
```

So it seems that `Wait(AsyncWait(d))` is not actually yielding execution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([Answered here](https://gitlab.com/lely_industries/lely-core/-/issues/161), but repeated below to make it easy to find.)

That's because you're scheduling the tasks with `Defer()` instead of `Post()`.

`Defer()` submits a task to a "strand" executor. A strand guarantees that tasks submitted to it never run concurrently. So it will only execute task B once task A finishes. This can be useful in multithreaded applications (such as when using `LoopDriver`) to prevent race conditions without having to use mutexes or other explicit synchronization mechanisms.

`Defer()` is probably not the most obvious name for this. It originally comes from the executors in [Boost.Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html) and is meant to indicate that the submitted task will not run concurrently with the task that does the submitting (`OnConfig()` in your example). In this case, it means "defer task A until `OnConfig()` is complete and defer task B until task A is complete".